# Git: egit shows wrong information

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

The screen shot on the right side of my branch on git local repo has same status as branch on git origin repo, this is correct.

When you look on the left side, it says that I have 15 commits to push to the origin repo and 7 commits to be pulled to the local repo. This is not correct. Any Idea why eclipse shows this incorrectly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, in the *History* view ***Show all changes in repository containing the selected resource*** is enabled:

[image]

See also: [EGit User Guide - Working with the Filter Settings](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Working_with_the_Filter_Settings)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure hotfix/H1.13.1... is merged from origin/hotfix/H1.13.1...? Could you check the file .git/config to verify it?